# How to get ExFAT working on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apt, ppa, exfat, fuse

I have read through a number of questions related to ExFAT and for 12.04 they recommend:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:relan/exfat
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fuse-exfat exfat-utils
```

However I run into problems at the first step with:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:relan/exfat
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
 tag:launchpad.net:2008:redacted
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~relan/+archive/ubuntu/exfat
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpwpgBPE/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpwpgBPE/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: "tag:launchpad.net:2008:redacted" not a key ID: skipping
recv failed
```

I assume that add-apt-repository and apt-add-repository are equivalent, certainly they result in the same error message.

When I then do:

```
sudo apt-get update
... SNIP ...
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4DF9B28CA252A784
```

While:

```
apt-cache search exfat
fuse-exfat - This driver is the first free exFAT file
exfat-utils - A set of utilities for creating, checking, dumping and labelling
```

Yet:

```
sudo apt-get install fuse-exfat
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fuse-exfat
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 26.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 98.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  fuse-exfat
Install these packages without verification [y/N]?
```

I would rather not install without verification :) So how do I resolve it?

Many Thanks in Advance!

-- Update -- 
The ppa author responded to an email I sent him:

Hi,

I've abandoned the PPA because the packages are now available in the
universe repository, thanks to Debian.

You should enable backports:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports

And then install exfat-fuse package:
http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-backports/exfat-fuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-- Update -- The ppa author responded to an email I sent him:

Hi,

I've abandoned the PPA because the packages are now available in the universe repository, thanks to Debian.

You should enable backports: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports

And then install exfat-fuse package: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-backports/exfat-fuse

Comment: For 12.04, this is the right answer.  Just for the record. here are the steps I took to enable  exFAT.  
1. add `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse` to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and 
2. run  `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse` to install required packages.